# Flexbox stacked on small devices

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 3 row grid, which is like this

https://codepen.io/Ramlev/pen/pXaqdg

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">asd</div>
  <div class="second">asd</div>
  <div class="third">asd</div>
</div>
```

and the stylesheet

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.first {
  flex: 1 0 250px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
}
.second {
  flex: 1 0 250px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}
.third {
  flex: 1 0 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
}
```

But when i go to a smaller device, i want the third row to fall under second row, and keep those two stacked to the right of the first row.

Does that make any sense?

Comment: Using grids and media queries?

Comment: You mean columns, not rows right?

Comment: When on large screen, the three divs should be next to each other. 1 - 2 - 3 and on smaller screens, 1 to the left, and 2 + 3 to the right above each other. To 3 "falls" under 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean up your code to start with by removing the flex shrink of 0 and the 250px flex basis since you really want halves and thirds with no real minimum width. By adding another wrapper around columns 2 and 3 and using a media query, you can get exactly what you described.

The mobile first default style can be achieved if the first column and the wrapper of columns 2 and 3 both have flex grow set to 1.

Then, once the breakpoint is reached, set the flex-grow property of the wrapper to 2 so it will be twice as big as column 1 and set it to display flex so it stops stacking columns 2 and 3.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.first {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
}

.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex: 2;
  }
}

.second {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}

.third {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">asd</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="second">asd</div>
    <div class="third">asd</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already have it working with a wrapping"wrapper" on the two last boxes, just asking to see if it is possible without the container, but it works.. Thank you.

Comment: Right on. I always figure that when it gets tricky to do things without a wrapper/container element, it will be extra tricky for me to troubleshoot it later even if I find a way that is too clever. I think you could get it to work in a maintainable way without the wrapper if you use grid instead of flex like @sibert mentioned.